# How do I get a parent to STOP being flex above a certain media breakppoint

Tags: css, tailwind-css, media-queries

I have a parent element

```
<div class="flex flex-col p-1 overflow-hidden">
   <div class="text-slate-400 text-xs line-clamp-1">Reported by</div>
   <div class="text-sm whitespace-nowrap line-clamp-1">User Name</div>
</div>
```

I want the flex to work for small screens up ONLY to medium and then STOP being flex.
I have tried on the parent element md:inline, md:inline-flex, md:block and none of those do it.

I have tried on the child elements md:flex-nowrap md:inline md:block
All using a variety of combinations.
Nothing seems to disable the 'flex' of the parent container once I get bigger than 768px (md width) and I'm just guessing at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd normally do that with a media query.

Comment: yeah - this is TailwindsCSS. That stuff is already done. The md: in the classes in my example is what shows that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes from the practice of Mobile-First responsiveness, essentially this means that you should design your UI with a mobile device in mind first, usually starting with a phone->tablet->laptop->desktop->`larger screens don't really matter`. Take a look at the modified code, specifically at the start. `md:block` basically means that upon reaching the medium breakpoint the display property for that element will be block instead of flex.

```
<div class="md:block flex flex-col p-1 overflow-hidden">
   <div class="text-slate-400 text-xs line-clamp-1">Reported by</div>
   <div class="text-sm whitespace-nowrap line-clamp-1">User Name</div>
</div>
```

Secondary, if you've already tried md:block and it isn't working it is because you aren't "Rebuilding" tailwindcss everytime you've made a change, use this command in the node.js terminal or whichever you prefer 
`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch` 
this rebuilds your project every single time you save the file. Make sure to change the input and output file paths according to your own.

Comment: Yeah - thanks. I tried all that and it didn't work, which is what made me post in the first place. After a bit of troubleshooting, I guess it seems like my rebuild 'watch' compiler was hiccupping for some reason. Restarting PHPstorm and the Docker container reset everything and got it back to normal. in PHPStorm I don't need to use that npm command manually. It's supposed to detect and run on changes. I sometimes need to run it manually, which I had also done just to make sure. Nothing was working until a good old fashioned 'reboot' of sorts put things back in order. Thanks for the help